# Payments using Stripe on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, stripe-payments

I am stuck... I was under the impression using Stripe in a Xamarin Forms application was easy, but that doesn't seem to be the case any more.

I have a Xamarin Forms (both Android and iOS) app that I want to integrate with Stripe for payments.  I have an API which creates a Payment intent, submits the amount and currency etc using the Stripe.net NuGet extension, and returns a client secret... but it turns out, there is no Stripe client available to use this client secret.

There are Android and iOS native elements controls which I should be able to somehow include in my Xamarin Forms application or the use of a webview and using stripe.js.

Can anyone tell me which of these two options is most suitable? I have never used binding for including Android and iOS packages (I'm not clued up on the individual platforms) and the webview seems to me to be a poor UX... I'm only speculating, because I don't know... I'm hoping there is someone on here who has experience with Xamarin FOrms and Stripe who can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet

Comment: Great! If I can use this, I'll be over the moon. As this is not an Elements implementation, does this require me to be PCI compliant to use this?

Comment: I also suspect I would need to create a custom way of dealing with 3D Secure?

Comment: Note that stripe-dotnet is a backend framework, so you'd still want to use Stripe.js on the frontend. There isn't currently a Xamarin-specific wrapper for Stripe,js. You may find some useful answers here, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924620/accepting-payments-in-xamarin-forms-with-stripes-payment-intent-api

Comment: Thanks Taintedzodiac... That is where I got my original info from... I've just found an example of this being used as a client on Xamarin Forms... I'm new in this area so I might be getting this wrong, but it looks like this guy has it working with 3D Secure too...  https://www.duckpage.dev/blog/stripe-paymentintent-with-3d-secure-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Check this article which helped me https://alexismeilland.medium.com/how-to-manage-stripe-payments-between-a-connected-account-and-a-customer-with-xamarin-forms-470f04e1be7