# Problems with GooglePay payment. OR_BIBED_10 error

Tags: android, xamarin, google-pay

When I try to test Google Pay in my release application, I get error: OR_BIBED_10

I checked all my settings in the app and in the google business console.
I wrote to Google technical support and did not receive a response.
This problem appeared in March 2022.

I don't understand what needs to be done to make it work :(

Help, please.

My payment provider is Stripe.

Request:

```
private GooglePaymentStripeRequest GetBaseStripeRequest() => new GooglePaymentStripeRequest
        {
            ApiVersion = 2,
            ApiVersionMinor = 0,
            MerchantInfo = new MerchantInfo
            {
                MerchantName = PartnerModule.Instance.Model.ApplicationName
            },
            AllowedStripePaymentMethods = new[]
            {
                new PaymentStripeMethod
                {
                    Type = "CARD",
                    Parameters = new PaymentParameters
                    {
                        AllowedAuthMethods = new[] { "PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS" },
                        AllowedCardNetworks = new[] { "AMEX", "DISCOVER", "MASTERCARD", "VISA" }
                    },
                    TokenizationSpecification = new TokenizationStripeSpecification
                    {
                        Type = "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
                        Parameters = new TokenizationSpecificationStripeParameters
                        {
                            Gateway = _gate.GatewayTitle,
                            GatewayMerchantId = (_gate as XXX.Payment.Gates.StripeGate.Stripe).PublicApiKey,
                            StripeVersion = "2.0",
                            StripeKey = (_gate as XXX.Payment.Gates.StripeGate.Stripe).PublicApiKey
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Can you debug to find what caused the problem? In addition, there is a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924620/accepting-payments-in-xamarin-forms-with-stripes-payment-intent-api).

Comment: Hi quak, this error code is related to an administrative issue with your merchant account that can only be resolved with intervention from the Google Pay. Give the support channel another go.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? Have the same error with 500 from `https://payments-pa.googleapis.com/payments/apis-secure/ui2/buyflowservice/initialize` and "OR_BIBED_10" while payment is going on.

Comment: @JoseLUgia do you know the communication channel with GPay support cause our chat seems silenced :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `adb` to view the details of the error, i.e.

```
adb -d logcat -s WalletMerchantError
```

Google Pay Request failed / Troubleshooting docs:

https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/support/troubleshooting#request-failed

Comment: I see nothing in terminal. Only this: _--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main_ :(